# Or condition in Java For Loop

Tags: java, for-loop

So I have a pretty basic problem, which I have no idea why it is failing. I know how to fix it using a different approach but I just wanted to understand why it was causing this problem.

```
static String kangaroo(int x1, int v1, int x2, int v2) {
   int last = (x1 < x2) ? x1 : x2;
   int first = (x1 > x2) ? x1 : x2;

   for(; x1 <= 2 || x2 < 100;){
       System.out.println(x1 + " " + x2);
       if(x1 != x2){
           x1 += v1;
           x2 += v2;
       } else if (x1 == x2){
           return "YES";
       }
   }
   return "NO";

   }
```

What this is doing is that even though the condition x1 <= 2 has been satisfied the loop keeps going. Why is that when I have specified it is either that condition or another which stops the loop?

Comment: What are the actual values for x1 and x2 you see?

Comment: (0,2,5,3) in that order x1 - 0, x2 - 5

Comment: So x1=0 and x2=2?  Or what?

Comment: Regardless, x2 is less than 100 (all those values are) so the loop condition is true and it continues.  You need a FALSE condition to stop.

Comment: @KidusAsmareAyele, I believe I have provided a more direct answer with a detailed explanation as to why this works best. Please review and consider it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What this is doing is that even though the condition x1 <= 2 has been
> satisfied the loop keeps going.

You are thinking about it the wrong way.  As long as the condition is true the loop will continue executing.  If you want it to break, the condition should fail.  Think about the most common example of a for loop :

Notice the loop **stops** when the condition is no longer satisfied.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   System.out.println("i = " +i);
}
```

Comment: Okay, I see your point, but isn't the condition no longer being satisfied because x1 is greater than 2?

Comment: Well you have an OR condition.  Is x2 < 100 still true?  If so, then the condition is still satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got it...but not quite. It looks like you're actually look for a `while loop`. A while loop executes code inside the brackets until a certain condition is met.

Here's an example of a while loop:

```
while(true) {
   System.out.println("I will run forever!");
}
```

You can use this to execute code until a condition is met. Here's an example:

```
int x = 3;
while(x < 100) {
   System.out.println("x is less than 100. Adding 3");
   
   x += 3;
}
System.out.println("If this line of code is executed, x should be greater than 100!");
```

We can apply this to your code by executing a while loop until `x1 == x2`.

```
//If x1 does not equal x2, run this code forever!
while(x1 != x2){
   x1 += v1;
   x2 += v2;
}
System.out.println("If we made it here, x1 == x2");
```

However, it is possible that x1 and x2 may never equal one another! Let's apply those terminating conditions you specified (those being: `if x1 is <= 2, stop and return "NO!"` and `if x2 is <= 100, stop and return "NO!"`)

```
while(x1 != x2) {
   //Terminating Conditions
   if(x1 <= 2 || x2 <= 100) {
      return "NO";
   }

   //If we made it here, we know x1 is > 2 and x2 is > 100

    x1 += v1;
    x2 += v2;
}
//If we made it here, x1 == x2
return "YES!";
```